# Sum values of column based on the unique values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a data frame of

```
Column1  Column2
1          20
2          25
3          30
2          40
4          18
1          24
```

and I want to sum Column2 based on the unique values of Column1. We can find sum based on a specific value such as 1 using this way:

```
df.loc[df['Column1'] == 1, 'Column2'].sum()
```

which correctly gives us 44. But how we can do it for all unique values in Column1 such that it produces this one

```
Column1  Column2
1          44
2          65
3          30
4          18
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum in pandas by unique index in several columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307732/how-to-sum-in-pandas-by-unique-index-in-several-columns)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `groupby`. You can find documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
df.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].sum()
Column1  Column2
1          44
2          65
3          30
4          18
```